# How to use .svg icon from local in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, icons

I am trying to show svg icon  which i added into my project's folder `assets/contact/tag.svg`  and defined it's path in pubspec.yaml.
but getting exception

```
Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#aeb88(), name:
I/flutter (10891):   "assets/contact/tag.svg", colorFilter: null)
```

I used [flutter_svg](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_svg) plugin to show svg icon

**CODE:**

```
class ProfileAboutMe extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileAboutMe({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: Container(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 24,
          top: 14,
          right: 24,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'ABOUT ME',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color(0xff4e4b6f),
                  ),
                ),
               SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/contact/tag.svg',
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                ),

                // IconButton(
                //     onPressed: () => print('abc'),
                //     icon: Icon(Icons.edit_outlined)),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff4e4b6f),
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text:
                        "Hey guys, This is Anna. I'm here to find someone for hookup. I'm not interested in something serious. I would love to hear your adventurous story",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

showing black container instead of icon:

[image]

My svg Icon screenshot:
[image]

my log message:

```
Syncing files to device Redmi 8A...                              1,240ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Redmi 8A is available at: http://127.0.0.1:60801/fltQBNjDVcA=/
W/Gralloc3( 8654): mapper 3.x is not supported
I/OpenGLRenderer( 8654): Davey! duration=3648ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=216833028460600, Vsync=216833211793926, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=216833215017697, AnimationStart=216833215155197, PerformTraversalsStart=216833215167020, DrawStart=216836489206393, SyncQueued=216836517323321, SyncStart=216836517942487, IssueDrawCommandsStart=216836518714206, SwapBuffers=216836674754727, FrameCompleted=216836677195925, DequeueBufferDuration=3498000, QueueBufferDuration=1371000, 
W/Looper  ( 8654): Slow Looper main: Long Msg: seq=10 plan=13:19:41.416  late=186ms wall=3464ms running=0ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver
I/Choreographer( 8654): Skipped 209 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/Looper  ( 8654): Slow Looper main: doFrame is 3499ms late because of 2 msg, msg 1 took 3464ms (seq=10 late=186ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)
I/flutter ( 8654): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8654): The following UnimplementedError was thrown in parseSvgElement:
I/flutter ( 8654): The <style> element is not implemented in this library.
I/flutter ( 8654): 
I/flutter ( 8654): Style elements are not supported by this library and the requested SVG may not render as intended.
I/flutter ( 8654): If possible, ensure the SVG uses inline styles and/or attributes (which are supported), or use a
I/flutter ( 8654): preprocessing utility such as svgcleaner to inline the styles for you.
I/flutter ( 8654): 
I/flutter ( 8654): Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#107cd(), name:
I/flutter ( 8654):   "assets/discover/scan.svg", colorFilter: null)
I/flutter ( 8654): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Try with Color property, else I think there is problem with your svg file try with other one.

Comment: I tried color(color:Colors.red)  property but nothing happining, showing red.

Comment: Did you tried using another svg icon ?

Comment: Please try restarting your emulator

Comment: @AR i have tried but same output

Comment: @iamnabink tried nothing happend

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma can you please post whole log error message

Comment: @iamnabink i have added my log message, please check

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma check my answer and if it helped you mark it as answer and upvote it please :) . Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Your problem and solution is clearly mentioned here:

```
I/flutter ( 8654): The <style> element is not implemented in this library.
I/flutter ( 8654): Style elements are not supported by this library and the requested SVG may not render as intended.
I/flutter ( 8654): If possible, ensure the SVG uses inline styles and/or attributes (which are supported), or use a
I/flutter ( 8654): preprocessing utility such as svgcleaner to inline the styles for you.
```

Let me clarify this for you:

`flutter_svg` package does not support `svg` consists of `internal css` like:

```
 <style>
       .....
  </style>
```

So in order to make it work, you need to remove the `internal css` and write `inline css` or use different svg picture or use a preprocessing utility such as [Svgcleaner](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner) to inline the styles for you.

You can download Svgcleaner into your OS, from [here](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/releases) , or [Direct Download Link - Executable File](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/releases/download/v0.9.5/svgcleaner_win32_0.9.5.exe) for windows os.

But I recommend that, you better use another `svg` picture which does not have `internal css` in it's code.

Comment: I tried cleaning the svg files using svgcleaner you linked here but still got the same error. But then I opened the cleaned svg files in vs code and saw that the <style> tag was still there. I commented the style tag and its contents. It's not throwing any error now. Is it fine like this or is there any problem with it? Will I need to do something else with the style tag?

Answer (score -2):

you can try using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Comment: Read question carefully before answering. Your answer is too short and does not have any explanation so it can be included in comment section.